# JQUERY LOad Controller Action on Change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to JQUERY.  This seems like it should be easy.

I'm trying to load a page on a change of the Drop Down called #AttDD below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#textbox1").click(function () {
                $("#textbox1").val('');
            });
            $("#AttDD").change(function () {
                //alert("Value: " + $('#AttDD option:selected').val());
                window.location = ("/Guest/Index/", {atton:('#AttDD option:selected').val()});
            });
        });
```

I know the OnChange portion is working, you can see from my commented alert below.  However how do I tell my JQUERY script to load a page/controller route when the drop down is changed?  Is there a better way to do this?

My controller is waiting on an optional atton parameter (hence the {atton: xxx} in the link I am trying to generate above.

Comment: try this $(document).on("change", '#AttDD', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
        var value = $(this).val();
        
        window.location = '/Guest/Index/' + value;
       
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like

```
window.location = "/Guest/Index/?atton=" + $('#AttDD option:selected').val();
```

please tell me if this work for you.

Comment: The problem is that the window.location is not doing anything.  I tested this by setting a completely different route, like Home/Index and still nothing happens.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the ?atton= setup?  I am wonderign because there are cases where I may need to send multiple values to this route.....

Comment: I suggest you add a javascript function to let you add N quantity of parameters to this URL, so this way you can pass multiple parameters to the route. Please don't forget mark my response as correct.

Comment: How would I add multiple parameters, for example what if i wanted the contents of a textbox (called textbox1) added as a second route paramter, like as a ?=SearchString

Comment: its messy but I did it as follows:

Comment: window.location = ("/Guest/Index/?atton=" + $('#AttDD option:selected').val() + "&SearchString=" + $('#textbox1').val());

Comment: If not are a huge quantity of characters you can try something like: `function myURLvals(param1, param2.param3){ var url="/Guest/Index/?"; url= url+param1; if(param2 != null){url= url+ "&"+ param2} return url} ... }` and in the window.location try: `window.location = myURLvals(); ` complete this code and test!